# Format does not except Amount:Decimal

Tags: pact-lang

I was writing over a simple payment contract and noticed that I was receiving the warning:

> We can only analyze calls to `format` formatting {string,integer,bool}
>   (not amount)

Below is my code, I realized if I remove the amount parameter on the bottom of my code I no longer receive the warning.. is there a way to adjust it?

```
  (defun pay (from:string to:string amount:decimal)
    (with-read payments-table from { "balance":= from-bal, "keyset":= keyset }
      (enforce-keyset keyset)
      (with-read payments-table to { "balance":= to-bal }
        (enforce (> amount 0.0) "Negative Transaction Amount")
        (enforce (>= from-bal amount) "Insufficient Funds")
        (update payments-table from
                { "balance": (- from-bal amount) })
        (update payments-table to
                { "balance": (+ to-bal amount) })
        (format "{} paid {}" [from to] ))))

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Pact property checking system doesn't currently support analysis of formatting decimals. Your example as written should actually be okay, but if we look at the [simple payment example](https://pact.kadena.io/example/SimplePayment) it includes this line: `(format "{} paid {} {}" [from to amount])`, where `amount` is a `decimal`.

If you need to check properties of code like this, the easiest way would be to use `integer` instead of `decimal`, since we can analyze the formatting of integers.

We can't currently analyze formatting of integers for a [technical reason](https://github.com/kadena-io/pact/issues/452) that should be fixable.